# Dir pagination on tab base in single page

Tags: angularjs

I'm using dir-pagination on Tab base on a single page in a single list collection paging work as below image. Open tab contains 4 rows but paging shows an incorrect count of entries.

[image]

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly missing pagination-id , please add that, it will resolve your issue.

```
<div dir-paginate="expression | itemsPerPage: 10"
     pagination-id="abcd"
</div>

<dir-pagination-controls
    pagination-id="abcd"
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Incase this does not solve your problem, please edit your question and all add your code so that we can better understand the problem, Thanks .

Best Of luck :)